# Get own applications in Django

Tags: python, django

Is there a way I can get a list of the applications that belong to a Django project itself (ignoring the apps that are installed with `pip`).

Said with other words: can I exclude the apps that were installed with `pip` from `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: it is basically iterating through django project folder and listing.

Comment: @VinayP Not all modules in the Django project folder are in `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: A possible good implementation is at [django_admin_tools](https://github.com/django-admin-tools/django-admin-tools/blob/master/admin_tools/dashboard/modules.py) in class AppList

Answer (score 3):

You can get all django apps using [django.apps](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.get_models),

```
In [35]: import django.apps

In [36]: models = django.apps.apps.get_models()

In [37]: myapps = set([x.__module__.split('.')[0]  for x in models])
```

`myapps` will give you all own django applications.

You can get all the models from `myapps` using,

```
In [89]: for o in myapps:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         x = django.apps.apps.get_app_config(o)
    ...:         print x.models
    ...:     except LookupError:
    ...:         pass
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, I am interested in retrieving models those are in my own apps. How do I achieve that?

Comment: Sorry but the original question was posted by someone else so I can not accept it, I just stumbled upon your answer which was similar to what I wanted. I could upvote, which I did

Answer (score 2):

You can loop through the apps using `get_app_configs`, then check the [`path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.path) attribute to see if they are in your project directory.

```
>>> from django.apps import apps
>>> for a in apps.get_app_configs():
...     if a.path.startswith("/path/to/project/"):
...         print("%s is in project directory" % a.name)
...     else:
...         print("%s is in %s" % (a.name, a.path))
```